# How do I enable "Logon as a service" dialog buttons?

Tags: group-policy

Group Policy newbie here. I need to be able to run some of my services as a user that also has access to SQL Server. How do I enable the "Add User or Group..." and "Remove" buttons on the "Logon as a service Properties" dialog? I am both a local administrator on the machine in question and a network administrator.

I have monkeyed around with GPMC.msc a bit, but it is not clear to me what steps I need to take to get this working.

(See screen cap).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the reason that the boxes are greyed out is because either 1) you are not an administrator on the machine and therefore do not have permission to modify the security policy, or B) the settings are already managed via Group Policy, which supersedes the ability to manage the settings locally.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @ryan I am both local and network admin. How does one go about finding where it has been disabled.

Comment: @Swim Use `gpresult /h results.htm` to generate a Group Policy report. Open it, and search for "Log on as a service"... you should then see what Group Policy is currently governing this setting.